# R. Using t-test, compare individual mean with global mean

Tags: r, t-test

I have a huge matrix of this form, with 1000000 rows and 10000 columns. This is a toy example:

```
A B C Mean
1 3 4 2.66
2 4 3 3
1 3 4 2.66
9 9 9 9
1 3 2 2
2 4 5 3.66
1 2 6 3
2 3 5 3.33
```

The rows in column "Mean" represent the mean of A, B and C for each row. On the other hand, the global mean of column "Mean" is 3.58. I would like to know, using a t-test and R, whether the mean in each row is significantly higher from the global mean. How can I get the p-values for comparison?. Comparing means between 2 groups is very simple using t.test(), but I am not able to find how to compare a single value with the mean of a group that includes that value.

Comment: The question is unclear. For example you say that "Mean" represents the mean of "A", "B", and "C" for each row. However there is a row where A=2, B=4, C=5. Their mean should be 3.66 but the "Mean" column shows 9.

Comment: Hello @KarolisKoncevičius, besides this error you noticed I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: Hello @Lucas the question is clear. I was just unsure if I understood it right when the text didn't agree with the table. Tried to provide an answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First here is a simulation of your scenario:

```
theData <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10, replace=TRUE),
                      b=sample(1:10, replace=TRUE),
                      c=sample(1:10, replace=TRUE)
                     )
totalmean <- mean(data.matrix(theData))
theData$Mean <- rowMeans(theData)
```

Your question as I understood it essentially is asking which of the rows have 3 values that are unlikely to be above the total mean by chance. You are familiar with a two-sample t-test which compares the means of two groups:

```
t.test(a, b)
```

What you need to do here is actually run a simpler version of a t-test which compares the mean of one group with a number:

```
t.test(a, mu=number)
```

Here `mu` parameter is a hypothesized value of the mean under the NULL hypothesis.

In addition you want to only check for scenarios where the mean of `a` is greater than the provided `number` and don't care about the cases when it's lower. For that you should use a one-sided test:

```
t.test(a, mu=number, alternative="greater")
```

In simpler terms - this test will return a probability that the mean of the provided `a` group would be *higher* than the provided `number` by chance. This probability is called the p-value.

This is so far all for a single row. In order to get this for every row you want to run the test on each row separately:

```
pvals <- numeric()
for(i in 1:nrow(theData)) {
  pvals[i] <- t.test(theData[i,1:3], mu=totalmean, alternative="greater")$p.value
}
```

This will give a p-value for every row:

```
> pvals
[1] 0.01382247 0.67918151 0.85176324 0.14543052 0.54297350 0.74618298 0.77880945 0.66752357 0.98761571 0.03683973
```

Alternatively you can use a dedicated package for that like `matrixTests` that allows you to compute all of these in one go. It will also be considerably faster:

```
library(matrixTests)
> row_t_onesample(theData[,-4], mu=totalmean, alternative="greater")

   obs     mean        var    stderr df  statistic     pvalue   conf.low conf.high alternative mean.null conf.level
1    3 9.000000  1.0000000 0.5773503  2  5.8889727 0.01382247  7.3141455       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
2    3 4.333333 16.3333333 2.3333333  2 -0.5428571 0.67918151 -2.4799664       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
3    3 4.666667  1.3333333 0.6666667  2 -1.4000000 0.85176324  2.7200096       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
4    3 7.666667  6.3333333 1.4529663  2  1.4223775 0.14543052  3.4240260       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
5    3 5.333333 14.3333333 2.1858128  2 -0.1219989 0.54297350 -1.0492086       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
6    3 5.333333  0.3333333 0.3333333  2 -0.8000000 0.74618298  4.3600048       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
7    3 4.333333  5.3333333 1.3333333  2 -0.9500000 0.77880945  0.4400192       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
8    3 4.666667 10.3333333 1.8559215  2 -0.5028948 0.66752357 -0.7525972       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
9    3 2.000000  1.0000000 0.5773503  2 -6.2353829 0.98761571  0.3141455       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
10   3 8.666667  2.3333333 0.8819171  2  3.4772732 0.03683973  6.0914814       Inf     greater       5.6       0.95
```

Final note: The column "Means" in your data is not necessary in this case.